# displacement between vectors in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a problem with a homework question.

The question reads as follows: A particle starts from a position R1 = <2.9, 4.5, 3.3> m. It is then moved through a displacement of 
$\delta$R2 = <4.9, 2.1, 5.8> m, and then moved 3.7 m in the direction of the vector 
R3 = <1.0, 1.0, 2.0> .

R1, R2 and R3 are all vectors.

My question is how would you work out the displacement in the direction of R3.

My attempt:

Delta R2 = Rf-Ri. We know Ri and therefore Rf = DeltaR2 + Ri = <-2,6.6, 2.5>
the position of the particle after moving 3.7 in the direction of R3(call this R4) = 3.7($\frac{R3}{|R3|}$) = <1.5, -1.5,3.0>

So to get displacement in direction of R3 would I just take R4 - Rf? As displacement is final position - initial position?

Thanks in advance and apologies for poor formatting I'm still getting the hang of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yor intuition for the last displacement is correct, but you are getting some confusion in signs. Using a slightly different notation:
$\ r_1=(2.9,4.5,3.3)$
$\Delta r_{12}=(4.9,2.1,5.8) \ so \ r_2 =r_1+\Delta r_{12}=(7.8,6.6,9.1)$
$\Delta r_{23} = (1.5,1.5,3.0) \ so \ r_3 = r_2 + \Delta r_{23} = (9.3,8.1,12.1)$

The total diplacement is $\ r_3-r_1 = \Delta r_{12} + \Delta r_{23} = (6.4,3.6,8.8)$

I hope this helps.